# Button Text Formats Don't Work On Older API's

Tags: android, button, formatting, textview

I'm trying to set a button with text that looks like this:

> *<del>$34.99</del>* $24.99

However, on some older devices, the formatting does not appear at all. I've tried `Html.fromHtml`, as well as building the `SpannableString` myself, and none of it works!

Comment: `Button`'s default style sets `textAllCaps` to `true`. Prior to Oreo, the transformation that involves treats the text as a plain `String`, so you end up losing any span formatting you've applied. If you were to set a style for your `Button`s with `textAllCaps` as `false`, it should fix your issue, without having to switch to `TextView`.

Comment: You're right! I just tried changing them back to Buttons, and that worked. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, changing the `Button` to a `TextView` seemed to do the trick!

**EDIT: using a `Button` works just fine, but you need to set `textAllCaps` to `false` for API's prior to 26. Thanks to @Mike M. for the explanation!**

The following code now works:

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(oldBuyPrice + newBuyPrice);
spannableString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, oldBuyPrice.length(), 0);
spannableString.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, oldBuyPrice.length(), 0);
buyButtonTextView.setText(spannableString);
```